# Mongoose versioning broken?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm sort of at a loss here. I was expecting that anytime an updated an object in mongoose the version would increment on __v. This does not appear to be the case. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongooseTest');

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', {
  name: String,
  manualVersion: Number,
  arr: []
});
var kitty = new Cat({
  name: 'Zildjian',
  manualVersion: 0,
  arr: []
});

kitty.save()
  .then(x => {
    x.manualVersion = x.manualVersion + 1;
    //x.arr.push(x.manualVersion); <-- pushing here makes '__v' be correct
    return x.save();
  })
  .then(() => Cat.findOne({}))
  .then(x => {
    x.manualVersion = x.manualVersion + 1;
    //x.arr.push(x.manualVersion); <-- pushing here makes '__v' be correct
    return x.save();
  })
  .then(() => Cat.findOne({}))
  .then(x => {
    console.log(x.toObject());

    // RESULT (from console.log and what is also in the DB):
    // {
    //   _id: 565386b058b2632c0886b160,
    //   name: 'Zildjian',
    //   manualVersion: 2,
    //   __v: 0,
    //   arr: []
    // }

  });
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the version only automatically increments if an update is made that could _potentially_ change the position inside of an array. That would explain why direct assignment is not updating it, but pushing something in is. You can call `.increment()` on it to force it.

Comment: Cool thanks yeah thats what I'm doing now

Answer (score 0):

```
x.increment().save();
```

in the above example fixes my problem. 'save()' appears to be idempotent as well so its cool to just call on every save as long as you know you are making changes.  According to one of the authors of mongoose versioning is only meant to be used with arrays and only increments for those. Ugh.

http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning

At the very least this should be clearly spelled out in the docs IMO as it is currently very ambigious...

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey